# Woocommerce default placeholder not gone in checkout form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce_checkout_fields to change labels and fields.Below is my code

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields) {


     $fields['billing']['billing_first_name'] = array(
            'label' => '',
            'placeholder' => _x('First Name*', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => true,
            'class' => array('checkout-billing-first-name')
        );
        $fields['billing']['billing_last_name'] = array(
            'label' => '',
            'placeholder' => _x('last Name*', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => true,
            'class' => array('checkout-billing-last-name')
        );
        $fields['billing']['billing_company'] = array(
            'label' => '',
            'placeholder' => _x('Company Name', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => false,
            'class' => array('checkout-billing-company')
        );
        $fields['billing']['billing_address_1'] = array(
            'label' => '',
            'placeholder' => _x('Address(Line 1)*', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => true,
            'class' => array('checkout-billing-addressL1')
        );
         $fields['billing']['billing_address_2'] = array(
            'label' => '',
            'placeholder' => _x('Address(Line 2)*', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => false,
            'class' => array('checkout-billing-addressL2')
        );

        return $fields;
    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields');
```

Everything works fine but placeholder for billing address 1 and billing address 2 is changing for only
in loading i.e after page is loaded default placeholder are shown.

Comment: Your code works just fine at my end.

Comment: If it's showing after the page is loaded, it's probably being dynamically changed via JavaScript.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try use filter woocommerce_default_address_fields.

For example:

```
function pawelprotas_wc_default_address_fields($fields){
    $fields['address_1']['placeholder'] = __('Street address *', 'loft');
    $fields['address_2']['placeholder'] = __('Apartment, suite, unit etc.', 'loft');

    return $fields;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'pawelprotas_wc_default_address_fields');
```

Answer (score 1):

First add the below filter to prevent replace placeholder from JS.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_country_locale_field_selectors' , 'override_billing_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );

function override_billing_checkout_fields( $locale_fields ) {
    $locale_fields = array(
        'address_1' => '',
        'address_2' => ''
    );
    return $locale_fields;
}
```

Then use the below filter

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields');
function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields)
{
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['placeholder'] = __( 'Address 1', 'woocommerce' );
    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the default placeholders:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields');
function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields)
{
$fields['billing']['billing_company']['placeholder'] = 'Business Name';
return $fields;
}
```